# Which is faster in PHP - sprintf or double quoted strings?

Tags: php, string, printf

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What is the best way to add two strings together?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/695124/what-is-the-best-way-to-add-two-strings-together)

Ignoring the data formatting benefits, which of these is the quickest? Or less memory hungry?
I expect the difference to be negligible.

```
$answer = "A String: {$string}";

$answer = sprintf('A String: %s', $string);
```

<sub>**PS:** I read a blog that discovered `echo $a, $b` was slightly faster than `echo $a . $b` (comma vs concatenate) because the latter creates a third value temporarily before echoing it.</sub>

Comment: The important answer is, "it doesn't matter". Use whichever one produces cleaner code. If you still care about performance, which you absolutely shouldn't, See http://www.phpbench.com/

Comment: This and the related "single-vs-double quotes" argument have been debated ad nauseum: [What is the best way to add two strings together?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/695124/what-is-the-best-way-to-add-two-strings-together)

Comment: Better duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3316060/php-single-quotes-or-double-quotes-for-variable-concatenation

Comment: @meagar The phpbench examples are interesting but look a bit flawed to me. None of the syntax case measurements subtracts the time spent on the for-loop. While the last test, which is testing loops, is completely empty and thus has little resemblence to real-world code.

Comment: I didn't mean to distract with discussion of concatenation which is why I put it as a PS. Really I'm interested in the parsing speed, not which is "best" or "worthwhile".