# Put dot between two variables in a string

Tags: php

how can I put a dot between two variables in mysql?
Something like this, but it doesn't work:

```
$query_filename->execute(array(".$value.".".$ext.", $key));
```

So the table would read (for example): file.txt

Thank you!

Comment: Why not `"{$value}.{$ext}"`?

Comment: `".$value."` will add 2 literal `.` characters to your string.

Comment: You could always concatenate the string in a command before...

Comment: possible duplicate of [What is the best way to add two strings together?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/695124/what-is-the-best-way-to-add-two-strings-together)

Comment: You have *way* too many `.`s and `"`s.  `$value.'.'.$ext`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"file.txt" (or any variation) isn't even remotely valid SQL. It isn't a query, just a filename.

In PHP, then to achieve what you want, try:

```
array($value . '.' . $ext,$key);
```

In MySQL, your query should include

```
CONCAT(value,".",ext)
```