# how to pass constants as part of a string in php

Tags: php

I am trying to pass the `app_id` and `app_key` in the response string. I am setting those as constants and then passing them in the string. I am getting syntax error

```
Parse error: syntax error, unexpected ':'
```

What am i doing wrong? sorry I am pretty new to PHP

```
    $app_id = 123456; 
    $app_key = '1234abcd5678';

    $query_string = https://apiresponse.htm?app_id=$app_id&app_key=$app_key;

    echo $query_string;
```

Comment: Strings have to be delimited by `'` or `"`. http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php. How else would PHP know that `http://...` is supposed to be a string?

Comment: Those are just variables, they're not constants. Also, you need to put quotes around your URL string.

Comment: @JonathonReinhart--I just realized that

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `$query_string` is not enclosed by single- or doublequotes.

In this case, as your string contains variables you should use doublequotes. That way, you don't have to break out of the string to add the variables.

```
$query_string = "https://apiresponse.htm?app_id=$app_id&app_key=$app_key";
```

If you were to use singlequotes, you would have do this:

```
$query_string = 'https://apiresponse.htm?app_id='.$app_id.'&app_key='.$app_key;
```

Read more on PHP Manual for [Strings](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php)

Answer (score 3):

You need to surround with quotes your string and concatenate your variables to avoid the error

```
$query_string = 'https://apiresponse.htm?app_id='.$app_id.'&app_key='.$app_key;
```

Comment: Or he could use double quotes and not use string concatenation.

Comment: Yeah he might do that as well

Answer (score 2):

... But `$app_id` and  `$app_key` are not constants, they are usual scalar variables (!).
So to express your  `$query_string` the best thing is

```php
$query_string = "https://apiresponse.htm?app_id=$app_id&app_key=$app_key";
```

more [fast](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14109681/287948) and  readable than concatenation.

---

Use [define()](http://www.php.net/define) to express constants:

```
  define('app_id','123456');
  define('app_key','1234abcd5678');
  $query_string = 'https://apiresponse.htm?app_id='.app_id.'&app_key='.app_key;
```

PS: now the best way the concatenation operator, like the @Fabio's suggestion.

Answer (score 1):

Use `"` for replace vars to values in string

`$query_string = "https://apiresponse.htm?app_id=$app_id&app_key=$app_key";`

It is cleaner than string concat (like `'a='.$a`)