# StringBuilder for PHP

Tags: php, stringbuilder

Has someone made a `StringBuilder` implementation in PHP?

Comment: Why would you want something like this?

Comment: Related: [php String Concatenation, Performance](http://stackoverflow.com/q/124067/106224) (many of the answers do dismiss the need for such a class, but all with good reasons)

Comment: You don't need StringBuilder in PHP, see my answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/124067/php-string-concatenation-performance/16112845#16112845

Answer (score 98, accepted):

**Note:**

This answer is from 2010, there might be stringbuilders that can improve the performance by now (judging from the comments below). I have not worked with php for a long time so my knowledge is not up to date. This answer might be out dated.

The following question might provide interesting information as well, all tough their conclusion seem to be the same.

[php String Concatenation, Performance](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/124067/php-string-concatenation-performance/39722317)

---

Why do you want to use a StringBuilder? Strings in php are mutable. Therefore performance is not an issue.

Just build string like this

```
$string = "start";
$string .= "appended string";
$string .= "appended string";
etc.
```

Comment: I would +1, but the concatenation operator is `.=`, not `+=` (`+=` is used for addition, which is a different operator from concatenation)...

Comment: oops, Thanks for pointing that out. To much used to java :P. Fixed it now.

Comment: yea i noticed that as well, from the C language :)

Comment: Yeah it's a pain :P. This error drives me crazy everytime i switch to php.

Comment: Than there is no such need over `StringBuilder` in php. Thanks for pointing out that...

Comment: This is so naive. You can't say this for sure; because you need to be familiar with php internal data structures. I haven't seen the source code, have you?

Comment: For the record, strings in PHP is _not_ - in any way - as fast as a string buffer.

Comment: Question: Is there any way to reserve 1000 bytes upfront, if you know your result will be large, even if you're constructing it ~4 characters at a time?

Answer (score 9):

You can use `sprintf` which is only a basic version but requires no extra libraries, examples Follow

```
$String = "Firstname %s, lastname %s, Age %d";
echo sprintf($String,"Robert","Pitt",22);
```

And also handles type casting and position replacements:

```
$format = "The %2$s contains %1$d monkeys. That's a nice %2$s full of %1$d monkeys.";
sprintf($format, $num, $location);
```

All though i do like the look of jacob's answer :)

taker a look at the great functionality of t
his function and its sister function here:
http://php.net/manual/en/function.sprintf.php

Comment: @Webnet Well it's good for strings that are defined elsewhere (such as in a translation file).  Otherwise it becomes nothing more than a magic string (which is the same concept as a [Magic Number](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Magic_number) )

Comment: L18n is exactly the best use for this function and also its sister function for char conversions: `printf("char 65 = %c", 65);`

Answer (score 4):

There are some implementations out there, however I don't see why you would need a StringBuilder in PHP,at least not for performance reasons. Plain string concatenation in PHP is faster than sprintf or the impelementation Jacob suggested.

Answer (score 1):

You don't need StringBuilder or StringBuffer in PHP , PHP is super handy I offer you , using from hereDoc and NowDoc if you you wish to keep PyString :

```
$YourString = "start";
$YourString .= <<<'EOD'

appended string
Example of string
spanning multiple lines
using nowdoc syntax.

EOD;

$YourString .= <<<buffer

appended string
Example of string
spanning multiple lines
using heredoc syntax.

appended string

appended string

buffer;
```

Comment: based on your answer, I made a suggestion of using variables and class fields right inside of the HERE_DOC/NOW_DOC block.

Answer (score 1):

Answer of @Amir, gave me inspiration to the fact that in PHP if you want 'named parameters' or 'positional' parameters, you don't need `sprintf`, but HERE_DOC/NOW_DOC works perfect. You can *even* *use this inside of a class*  for properties and call getters.

```
class MyClass{

     private $property;

     private $stock; // some other object with getter 'getSomeProperty()'

     function __toString(){

         $localvar = 'Localvar';
         $localvar2 = 'Localvar2';
         return <<<HERE_DOC
           {{ 
              fqsn: {$this->stock->getSomeProperty()},
              property: {$this->property},
              localvar: {$localvar},
              localvar2: $localvar2
           }}
HERE_DOC;
      } // end __toString()
 } // end MyClass
```