# PHP get words with length longer than 3 from string

Tags: php

Is there a function that can cut words from a string that are small length e.g. "the, and, you, me, or" all these short words that are common in all sentences. i want to use this function to fill a fulltext search with criteria

before the method:

```
$fulltext = "there is ongoing work on creating a formal PHP specification.";
```

outcome:

```
$fulltext_method_solution = "there ongoing work creating formal specification."
```

Comment: What you have tried so far can you please post your efforts

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
$fulltext = "there is ongoing work on creating a formal PHP specification.";

$words = array_filter(explode(' ', $fulltext), function($val){
             return strlen($val) > 3; // filter words having length > 3 in array
         });

$fulltext_method_solution = implode(' ', $words); // join words into sentence
```

Comment: welcome, note that it is using closure function, which require `php >= 5.3`. Also `$words` is array, implode it as you need. @user3485007

Comment: i saw it, also tested the code and saw indeed each word was an index.

Answer (score 3):

try this:

```
 $fulltext = "there is ongoing work on creating a formal PHP specification.";
$result=array();
$array=explode(" ",$fulltext);
foreach($array as $key=>$val){
    if(strlen($val) >3)
        $result[]=$val;
}
$res=implode(" ",$result);
```

Comment: why don't you use `implode()` ?

Comment: For the cost / performance you concern, please read [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/124067/php-string-concatenation-performance).

Comment: @Raptor i'll go through this.Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

try this:

```
$stringArray = explode(" ", $fulltext);
foreach ($stringArray as $value)
{
    if(strlen($value) < 3)
         $fulltext= str_replace(" ".$value." " ," ",$fulltext);
}
```

**Here is a working [DEMO](http://phpfiddle.org/lite?code=%3C?php%5Cn%20$fulltext%20=%20%22there%20is%20ongoing%20work%20on%20creating%20a%20formal%20PHP%20specification.%22;%5Cn%20$stringArray%20=%20explode(%22%20%22,%20$fulltext);%5Cn%20foreach%20($stringArray%20as%20$value)%5Cn%20%7B%5Cn%20if(strlen($value)%20%3C%203)%5Cn%5Ct%5Ct%5Cn%20$fulltext=%20str_replace(%22%20%22.$value.%22%20%22%20,%22%20%22,$fulltext);%5Cn%20%7D%5Cn%20echo%20$fulltext;%5Cn?%3E%5Cn)**

Answer (score 2):

You can simply use `implode`, `explode` along with `array_filter`

```
echo implode(' ',array_filter(explode(' ',$fulltext),function($v){ return strlen($v) > 3;}));
```

or simply use `preg_replace` as

```
echo preg_replace('/\b[a-z]{1,3}\b/i','',$fulltext);
```

Answer (score 1):

Simply explode the string and check for the `strlen()`

```
$fulltext = "there is ongoing work on creating a formal PHP specification.";

$ex = explode(' ',$fulltext);
$res = '';
foreach ($ex as $txt) {
    if (strlen($txt) > 3) {
    $res .= $txt . ' ';
    }
}
echo $res;
```

Answer (score 1):

By using `preg_replace`

```
echo $string = preg_replace(array('/\b\w{1,3}\b/','/\s+/'),array('',' '),$fulltext);
```

Answer (score 1):

This will also produce the desired results:

```
<?php
    $fulltext = "there is ongoing work on creating a formal PHP specification.";
    $fulltext = preg_replace('/(\b.{1,3}\s)/',' ',$fulltext);
    echo $fulltext;
?>
```